# Rewrite the Wordpress URL from custom plugin

Tags: rewrite-rules

I have created a plugin in wordpress. I am making a cURL request to the server and server response is coming to new index.php. Which is in my_plugin/newfolder/newfolder/index.php.

Now from the server side it post the response to my_plugin/newfolder/newfolder/ but it makes problem to other workflows in my application. So I have to handle the post response URL to my_plugin/newfolder/newfolder  with out slash from my plugin.

How can I do this? I have checked flush_rewrite_rules but it is not helping me.

Please help me into this.. Your Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[`plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_url) will return the URL of the current files directory. Usage would be:

```
$url = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/newfolder/newfolder/index.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method mentioned by Eric or can create a **Custom menu** with some **Url** in your **Custom plugin**.

Just write all your code in that menu to get data returned by the curl request.